# Codeigniter secure login systems

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I've used codeigniter as php framework in my project. Someone says its so vulneratble in login process and he can easily login without password. I've just used md5 hashing in password for secure login. I know that is not enough. Can anyone suggest me any more sucurity process in this regard? Here is my log in controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Admin_login extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    session_start();
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('url');        
    $this->load->model('admin_model', 'Admin_model', true);
}

public function index(){
        if(is_loggedin())
        {
            get_access_controller();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('login_admin', '');
        }
    }  

   function login_check()
        {
            $data['username']  = $_POST['username'];
            $data['password']  = md5($_POST['password']);            
            $adminInfo = $this->Admin_model->login_check($data); 

        if($adminInfo)
        {                
            $_SESSION['admin_id']           = $adminInfo['admin_id'];
            $_SESSION['admin_name']         = $adminInfo['admin_name'];
            $_SESSION['school_id']         = $adminInfo['school_id'];
            $_SESSION['is_superadmin']     = $adminInfo['is_superadmin'];
            $_SESSION['is_loggedin']        = 1;

            message('Loggedin successfully');
            get_access_controller();
        }
        exception('invalid login information');
        redirect('admin_login');exit;
    }

    function logout()
    {
       unset($_SESSION['admin_id'],$_SESSION['admin_name'],$_SESSION['school_id'],$_SESSION['is_loggedin'],$_SESSION['is_superadmin']); 
       message('Successfully logout');
       redirect('admin_login');exit;
    }
}
```

and my login model here

```
if(!defined('BASEPATH'))
exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Admin_model extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }
    /**For Admin Login Portion**/
  function login_check($data)
    {
        $user = $data['username'];
        $password = $data['password'];        
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_admin WHERE email = '$user' AND password = '$password' AND status = 1 LIMIT 1";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query->row_array();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

For password hashing, have a look at the PHP passwords API -see for password_hash() and password_verify(), for example-, if your PHP version matches with it.

Then, you must escape the values you get from the client, like password, login : here, you do nothing about securing your input values, you're exposed to SQL injections.
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#escaping-queries

Answer (score 0):

Since you are executing a query without any validation, it may be vulnerable for [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. you can use query bindings for better security.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_admin WHERE email = ?1 AND password = ?2 AND status = 1 LIMIT 1";
$query = $this->db->query($sql, ($user, $password));
```